# What is the relationship between manufacturers barebones and performace?

Tags: windows, performance

Assuming that I could choose between two similar machines(same processor, memories, chipset and HDDs) but different barebones manufacturers, such as Acer or Asus, could I check for another parameters(unless machine's price) that could affect the system performance and durability?

I mean, what are the mainly differences between two similar barebones but different manufacturers that could affect some performance parameter(such as Windows Seven boot time, benchmark score or game performance)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure there's anything specific left, other than situational need, or opinion.  But I can tell you tried to make it an on-topic question, so I'll try and give an on-topic answer. :)

What can make the difference between the remaining factors?

- Design
- Manufacturing
- Feature-set (options)

How should you choose? Don't know for you, but I use this list:

- Defective product return procedures (aka RMA, they'd better be easy and accommodating).
- Past experience with the brand(s).
- Your comfort level in the relationship you have with the manufacturer (and/or its chosen chain of supply).

Answer (score 2):

One more differentiating parameter would be the power supply wattage, this affects which video cards you could use.  For example, 200W supply will prevent you from using the better video cards, if video performance will matter to you (you did mention game performance).